# Data from Service is not working with ng-autocomplete

Tags: angular, autocomplete

I am trying to bind ng-autocomplete with dynamic data(from database) through a array of object . If I am passing static value to that array ,Auto Complete works fine, but when I set value of Array from Service. Auto Complete does not bind and gives an error in console.

I added the static array of object to check if it works or not, that worked perfectly, then i tried added the same data through service but code didn't work. I think there is something wrong with the way I am initializing  array. I am calling serivce in ngOnInit and then assigning the data to array.

```html
<div class="ng-autocomplete">
                <ng-autocomplete [data]="clientReactive"  
                                 formControlName="ClientName"
                                 [searchKeyword]="keyword"
                                 (selected)='selectEvent($event)'
                                 (inputChanged)='onChangeSearch($event)'
                                 (inputFocused)='onFocused($event)'
                                 [itemTemplate]="itemTemplate"
                                 [notFoundTemplate]="notFoundTemplate">
                </ng-autocomplete>

                <ng-template #itemTemplate let-item>
                  <a [innerHTML]="item.ClientName"></a>
                </ng-template>

                <ng-template #notFoundTemplate let-notFound>
                  <div [innerHTML]="notFound"></div>
                </ng-template>
              </div>
```

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ClientDetailsService } from '../SupportProjectServices/client-details.service';
import { ClientDetails } from '../Models/client-details.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-payment-details',
  templateUrl: './payment-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./payment-details.component.scss']
})
export class PaymentDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  paymentDetails: FormGroup;
  keyword = 'ClientName';
  clientReactive: ClientDetails[] = [];


//STATIC DATA WHICH IS WORKING FINE
  //[{
  //  AddressLine: "Complax",
  //  City: "12",
  //  ClientCode: "XXwe1",
  //  ClientId: 1049,
  //  ClientName: "XXXX",
  //  ContactNumber: "8467156",
  //  Country: "2",
  //  EmailAddress: "admin123@xxxta.in",
  //  Industry: "",
  //  NatureOfBusiness: "2",
  //  NoOfEmployee: 12,
  //  OtherReferenceNote: "12",
  //  Password: "123",
  //  PinCode: "1221212",
  //  State: "1212",
  //}, {
  //  AddressLine: " Complax",
  //  City: "12",
  //  ClientCode: "pinku",
  //  ClientId: 1049,
  //  ClientName: "pinku ",
  //  ContactNumber: "843234234234",
  //  Country: "2",
  //  EmailAddress: "admin123@luxnx.inx",
  //  Industry: "",
  //  NatureOfBusiness: "2",
  //  NoOfEmployee: 12,
  //  OtherReferenceNote: "12",
  //  Password: "123",
  //  PinCode: "1221212",
  //  State: "1212"
  //}];



  constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder, private _clientService: ClientDetailsService) {

  }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.paymentDetails = this._fb.group({
      ClientName: ['', Validators.required]
    });

    this._clientService.GetClientListArray().subscribe((data: ClientDetails[]) => {

      this.clientReactive = data;
      console.log(this.clientReactive);
    }, (error: any) => { console.log(error); });

  }


  selectEvent(item) {
    // do something with selected item
  }

  onChangeSearch(val: string) {
    // fetch remote data from here
    // And reassign the 'data' which is binded to 'data' property.
  }

  onFocused(e) {
    // do something when input is focused
  }

}
```

AutoComplete should show Client Name on KeyPress.Same as it works for static Data.

http://smit1.luspl.com/error.png

Original Post form where i am implementing ng-autocomplete

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-ng-autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

you bind `countriesReactive` to the data attribute,
but in the subscribe function you set the response to the `clientReactive`.

so `countriesReactive` stays `undefined`.

Comment: thanks for response, I have edited the question but the issue stay the same, now after inspecting i have set  keyword="Client" , but the data from array was in small Letter  'client'. Now its working fine, all problem was because of the keyword .